How to save raster as int16 / compressed using SaveGDAL from richdem
I am using the python package richdem to calculate a slope map from my DEM file.
dem_file = richdem.LoadGDAL(os.path.join(output_dir, f'DEM_{region_name_clean}_EPSG{EPSG}_resampled.tif'))
slope = richdem.TerrainAttribute(dem_file, attrib='slope_degrees')
richdem.SaveGDAL(os.path.join(output_dir, f'slope_{region_name_clean}_EPSG{EPSG}_resampled.tif'), slope)

The saved file is very big in size. I assume that the reason is that the values are saved as floats instead of ints. How can I specify this? Is there a compression option also?
Here is the SaveGDAL() function defined.
Here is the origin. It shows a "compress" argument. But when I use richdem.SaveGDAL(filename, data, compress=True) I get an error.
Is there a quick alternative to save using rasterio?

You could test the effect of compression first with gdal_translate https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal_translate.html. gdal_translate -of GTiff -co compress:deflate  resampled.tif resampled_compressed.tif. If you have a slope map with degrees as units, would you really like integer data type with only full degrees?

how do I use this function in python?
Full degrees is definitely enough precision. No need for floats.

Sorry, I do not master Python. If command line is not OK for you, could you open the file from richdem with QGIS and use Save as... for conversion? By the links that you provided, richdem is not prepared for doing anything advanced (If you need to do something more complicated, look at the source of this function, and the only option in the source is to apply deflate compression). So maybe the best option is to let richdem to save the tiff with its defaults and continue for example with rasterio, that certainly can use many compression methods and change the datatype as you wish.

thanks for your help! Then I think I will use rasterio for the compression and making sure it is saved as int

The SaveGDAL source is pretty simple and uses either GDAL or rasterio to save the data.  You could re-implement either of those functions yourself and add in the type conversion and compression.
Here's a rasterio version
import numpy as np
import richdem
import rasterio as rio

def save_using_rasterio(filename: str, rda: richdem.rdarray, dtype: str='float32', **kwargs) -> None:
    """" 
    Modified from https://github.com/r-barnes/richdem/blob/master/wrappers/pyrichdem/richdem/__init__.py#L391
    RichDEM is GPL v3 licensed https://github.com/r-barnes/richdem/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
    """

    crs = rda.projection
    transform = rio.Affine.from_gdal(*rda.geotransform)
    # richdem uses -9999 as the nodata value. 
    # if you use an unsigned integer (uint*) dtype, you will need to
    #  - change NoData values in the array, and
    #  - update below to use new nodata value
    nodata = rda.no_data
    metadata = {str(x): str(y) for x, y in rda.metadata.items()}

    if getattr(np, dtype) != rda.dtype:
        rda = np.array(rda).astype(dtype)

    with rio.open(
            filename,
            "w",
            width=rda.shape[1],
            height=rda.shape[0],
            count=1,
            dtype=dtype,
            crs=crs,
            transform=transform,
            nodata=nodata,
            **kwargs
    ) as f:

        f.write(np.array(rda), 1)
        f.update_tags(**metadata)


input='dem.tif'
output = 'slope.tif'

dem_file = richdem.LoadGDAL(input)
slope = richdem.TerrainAttribute(dem_file, attrib='slope_degrees')
save_using_rasterio(output, slope, 'int32', compress="LZW", tiled="True")


